# Prove (or disprove) that $\Bbb N$ is the set of all cluster points of $(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{(x_{n_k}):n\in\Bbb N\}$ a partition of $(x_n)$ such that $\lim_{k\to \infty}(x_{n_k})=n$. Prove that $\Bbb N$ is the set of all cluster points of $(x_n)$

I think the statement is true. A cluster point is defined as the limit point of a subsequence. I dont know how to show that doesnt exists some subsequence out of the partition that have a limit.

Let some subsequence $(x_h)\notin \{(x_{n_k}):n\in\Bbb N\}$ such that $\lim (x_h)=q\notin\Bbb N$. Then my first attempt is to say that because $(x_h)$ is infinite then infinitely many points must belong to some subsequence $(x_{n_k})$.

But the family $\{(x_{n_k}):n\in\Bbb N\}$ is infinite, then I can just construct some function that take finite numbers of points from each $(x_{n_k})$ to construct $(x_h)$, then the above argument is not suitable.

Some hint will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the statement is not true : let us denote $(p_n)_{n\ge 1}$ the increasing sequence of prime numbers.

Then we define :

- for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for $1\le k \le n,\ u_{p_n^k} = \frac{1}{2}$
- for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for $k>n$, $u_{p_n^k} = n$
- $u_n = 0$ otherwise

Denote, for $n\ge 1$, $m(n,k) = p_n^k$, and for $n=0$ you take the remaining indexes : $m(0,k)$ takes all the remaining values, in any order.

$ $

Then for all $n>0$, $x_{m(n,k)} = x_{p_n^k} \underset{k\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow} n$, and $x_{m(0,k)} = 0 \underset{k\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. But $\frac{1}{2}$ is also a cluster point of $(x_n)$, because there are infinitely many indexes $i$ such that $x_i = \frac{1}{2}$.

You can generalize that in the following way : given any closed subset $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$, you can find a sequence $(x_n)$ satisfying your conditions and also that the set of its cluster points if $F \cup \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I see. One question: if we set that the elements of $(x_n)$ are all different, then the statement could be true?

Comment: No, you could still find a counterexample : in my example, you just have to replace $\frac{1}{2}$ with $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot p_n^k}$ in the first line, then replace $n$ with $n + \frac{1}{p_n^k}$, and in the third line replace $0$ with a sequence bounded by $\frac{1}{4}$ and converging to $0$ (when n goes infinity). You can check that the set of cluster points does not change, but now all you elements are distinct.